# Invoke AWS API by adding authorization data to URL not working c#

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services

Invoke AWS API by adding authorization data to URL not working c#

this is the link I have refered https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html

For below code I am getting signature not matching error

//public static string url = "https://aws-url-host.com/v1/employees";
// With query string - as example

Comment: https://gist.github.com/yvanin/0bdf68c1139ad698519e ..I have referred this link ..but auth is attached to header not URL ...please help

Comment: Are you trying to invoke Amazon S3 API? Presigned URL only work with S3